# Falha no Deploy Aplicação Python/Flask no Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku

Olá, estou iniciando minha jornada com o Python e Flask, desenvolvi uma aplicação e estou atualmente tentando subir ela para o Heroku, porém estou com a seguinte mensagem de erro no log do painel:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

pesquisei aqui e até achei algumas respostas porem muito superficiais,  abaixo segue o meu código e gostaria de uma ajuda para entender onde tenho que altera, vou detalhar aqui os arquivos de Procfile também, ficaria grato se alguém puder ajudar.

**Arquivo Procfile**

```
web: python app.py
```

**app.py final do arquivo**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui solucionar o caso, só alterei o arquivo principal da forma que segue abaixo:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Aplicação rodando 100%.